# Disconnecting a complete graph by removing edges randomly

Tags: graphs, social-networks

Given a complete graph with $n$ nodes, I remove edges randomly with probability $p$ such that I want to disconnect the graph.

I want to find out the minimum number of edges that I must remove randomly to disconnect the graph. Also the value of $p$ where I can disconnect the graph by removing the least number of edges.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: This is just the standard [Erdős–Rényi $G(n,p)$ model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model), except that, by starting with a complete graph and deleting edges, you're looking at $G(n,1-p)$.

Comment: Minimum number is denitely $n$, are you looking for the estimated number of edges that need to be removed?

Answer (score 3):

For your first question, an empty graph becomes connected roughly when $n\log n$ random edges are inserted into it, in a way quantified in Erdős and Rényi's fundamental paper *On the evolution of random graphs*, and recounted in textbooks on random graphs.

Your second question is not stated precisely and so is difficult to answer.